# Renting or hosting a public NPM repository

Tags: node.js, github, npm, hosting, server

Say I'm developing a large Node.js framework geared towards a specific market. People would use this framework to write and share their software, just like they would with NPM. The problem is I don't want to pollute the default NPM registry and I also want to control my own. I also want a clean repository where only modules relating to my framework would be stored.

My question, because NPM is flexible enough to let us override the default repository, what are my options for setting up an empty public NPM repository? Is there a managed host I can pay and have them set everything up for me? Is it better to manage it myself? Can I use a service like Digital Ocean or Linode? or perhaps I can just leverage a service like GitHub and bypass NPM altogether?